# Transpose response object array to another different object array

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to figure out how to transpose response into a interface i created for storage.

i.e.

```
interface TestInterface {
name: string,
count: number
}

http.get("localhost:8088/api/getdata")
.map(res => res.json()
.subscribe(
(data) => {

// transpose the response into array of TestInterface

});
```

The response returns a array of objects in following format:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "54d130ce-0812-e711-b861-f01faf23929d",
    "Name": "First Name Attempt",
    "Description": "asd",
    "Count": 5
  },
  {
    "Id": "6f08ca4a-0d12-e711-b861-f01faf23929d",
    "Name": "Second Attempt",
    "Description": "One Site",
    "Count": 3
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it manually like this

```
interface TestInterface {
  name: string,
  count: number
}

http.get("localhost:8088/api/getdata")
  .map(res => res.json())
  .map((data: any[]) => {
    let arr: TestInterface[] = [];
    data.forEach(o => {
      let obj: TestInterface = {};
      obj.name = o.Name;
      obj.count = o.Count;
      arr.push(obj);
    });
    return arr;
  })
  .subscribe((data: TestInterface[]) => {
    // data here

  });
```